# python 3.x about append function——IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append

```
import numpy as np
import pandas 

data=pandas.read_table('u.data',names=['user id','item id','rating','timestamp']

user=pandas.read_table('u.user', sep='|',names=['user id ','age','gender','occupation','zip code'])

item=pandas.read_table(r'u.item', sep='|',names=['movie id','movie title','release date','video release date',
'IMDb URL','unknown','Action','Adventure','Animation',"Children's", 
'Comedy','Crime','Documentary','Drama','Fantasy','Film-Noir', 
'Horror','Musical','Mystery','Romance','Sci-Fi','Thriller',' War',' Western'])

data.sort_values('user id', inplace=True)

Averge=pandas.pivot_table(data, values='rating', columns=['user id'], aggfunc='mean')

M=[]
F=[]

#There is an error 

for i in range(944):
    if  user.iloc[i]['gender']=='M':
        M.append(Averge[i+1])
    else:
        F.append(Averge[i+1])

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: It looks like you question is all code. You will need to provide context to your question, and format all your code blocks (select them, and then press <Ctrl-K>)

Comment: Thank you! I try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append a subset of the `Averge` data frame, but you are not indexing the data frame correctly.  If you want the `i+1` row of `Averge`, use `.iloc`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':[9,8,7]})
for i in range(2):
    print(df.iloc[i+1])

# output
bar    8
foo    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
bar    7
foo    3
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry,My English is poor.
I hope that you will kown what I want to express.

Thank you for andrew_reece's hint!
Now I have solved it!

First,for i in range(943): 944 beyond the bound, you had better know the data.
second,because my data is special, Averge.iloc[0][i+1] is right. Only one row.
just like it!

```
Averge=pandas.pivot_table(data, values='rating', columns=['user id'], aggfunc='mean')

M=[]
F=[]

for i in range(943):
    #944 will make it-> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
    if  (user.iloc[i]['gender']=='M'):
        M.append(Averge.iloc[0][i+1])
    else:
        F.append(Averge.iloc[0][i+1])  #df.iloc[0][1] the first data
```

If everyone has something wrong,welcome !